# Unable to properly loop through keys AND values in a VB6 For Each loop

Tags: foreach, vb6

I'm making a program in VB6, and I can't properly loop through a String dictionary.

I've tried both ways of accesssing a value in the collection. `Collection(Key)`, and `Collection.Item(Key)`.

```vb
Dim line As Variant
Dim thismsg As New Collection
Dim thissection As String
For Each line In Split(NetRcv, vbLf)
    If Left(line, 3) = "BLK" Then
        thissection = Right(line, Len(line) - 3)
        MsgBox thissection
        GoTo nctlrParseLoopNext
    End If
    If Left(line, 3) = "BND" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    Dim key, value As String
    key = Left(line, InStr(line, " "))
    value = Right(line, InStr(line, " "))
    thismsg.Add key, value
nctlrParseLoopNext:
Next line
Dim member As Variant
For Each member In thismsg
    MsgBox member
    MsgBox thismsg(member)
Next member
```

The string in `NetRcv` is the following:

```
BLK modeswitch
mode codeslave
BND
```

I expect to see this sequence of MsgBoxes ...

```
modeswitch
mode
codeslave
```

... with possibly trailing spaces somewhere.
I see the first two, and then it errors with

```
Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

I don't understand why this error occurs.

`member` *is* the key, correct?

If it is, then there's no reason this error should pop up.

Comment: `Collection` *is not* a Dictionary. Use `Scripting.Dictionary` instead. `Collection` internally is a linked list.

Comment: Do you want an example of Dictionary use?

Comment: oh. sorry. I assume I was using `Collection` exactly like `Scripting.Dictionary`. so `Collection` is basically the same thing as .NET's `List<>`?

Comment: I am not sure about .NET<List>, but I am sure the VB6/VBA `Collection` has indexing speed O(N) (stumbled on it many times in large projects), so I infer it must be internally implemented as a list.

Comment: Personally I never ever use `Collection`. It's main advantage - ability to gather heterogenous objects is usually its another weakness, including your case. Stick with Arrays or Scripting.Dictionary.

Comment: `For Each member In thismsg` will iterate through the collection values. So inside the loop, member will have the value stored in the collection, it's not the key. The exception could be that the call `thismsg(member)` is not valid.

Comment: Also - I don't believe that this line `value = Right(line, InStr(line, " "))` is going to do what you want it to. `InStr` returns an offset into the string.  `Right` expects the number of characters to pull from the right side of the string.

Comment: I'm a dinosaur coder and I abhor "goto"  First time in decades I've even seen anyone use it.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski `Collection`'s `Item` is `O(N)` only for integral indexes. For string keys access it's `O(log N)` and `For Each` enumeration is `O(1)`. There is no equivalent container in .Net framework but we use it like `Dictionary<string, object>` mostly and never access it by index so the performance (and memory usage) is far better than `Scripting.Dictionary` counterpart.

Comment: @wqw if you happen to know what is the underlying data model of the `Collection`, would you care to answer `https://stackoverflow.com/q/57111861/1261153`?

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you have inverted the value and key.  This:

```
thismsg.Add key, value
```

should be this:

```
thismsg.Add value, key
```

See here for the docos on the `Add` method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-visual-basic-for-applications