# What exactly is the VBA/VB6 Collection?

Tags: vba, vb6, containers

For integer keys the speed of indexing is `O(N)`, so it looks like it is a list. But apparently (wqw's comment in [Unable to properly loop through keys AND values in a VB6 For Each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57066954/1261153)) access time for string keys is `O(log(N))`... Maybe it is a tree built on top of single-linked list (indexing the list elements)?

I tried hard to get the documentation about this, but all I can find is how to *use* the `Collection`, never what is its data model.

Comment: It's a binary tree over a linked list which is a very weird ADT. Check out this thread (and other threads linked there) -- [How to loop *keys* (not values) of a Collection](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?871471-VB6-VBA-Collection-keys)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll find much of anything regarding the implementation details of VBA.Collection. (Official usage reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)

The general advice is to consider using the VBScript Dictionary object instead; certainly use that instead if you need access to the keys. According to this, Dictionary is also faster up to a point: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/comparing-two-lists-vba-udf-shootout-between-linear-search-binary-search-collection-and-dictionary/

Another alternative I've done myself was to make use of the .NET Hashtable (making reference to mscorlib.dll). I've not done any performance tests of that versus VBScript Dictionary, so I don't if it's worth the effort (but it was fun to implement). An example is at [Cannot iterate Hashtable in VBA (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677949/cannot-iterate-hashtable-in-vba-excel).